# How to update admin front end invoice/order numbers

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0

I've changed increment_id directly to the database table mage_sales_flat_invoice only one row, in order to set a special invoice number.

My problem is related at front end of administration invoice page.

How do I update invoice numbers? They seems to be cached.

Answer (score 1):

Correct table is eav_entity_store with entity_id = 6(invoice entity) in that table you need to change the increment id.After this place order , create invoice and check your new Invoice increment ID this will work.
Do not forget to clear cache.

Comment: I need to change an invoice already created and shipped

Answer (score 1):

The admin page grid is driven from the data in the `sales_flat_invoice_grid` table.

You would need to change it there too.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the  increment_last_id in eav_entity_store table. To find the correct entity_type_id for order do

Find the entity_type_id for orders

```
SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'order';
```

Change your Order Increment ID on All Stores

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_last_id='XXXXXXXXXX'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order';
```

Change your Invoice Increment ID on a Specific Store

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_last_id='XXXXXXXXXX'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='invoice' AND eav_entity_store.store_id = 'Y';
```

See

- [Changing Magento Order, Invoice and Shipping Number](http://chilipepperdesign.com/2009/07/09/changing-magento-order-invoice-and-shipping-numbers/)
- [How to Change the Order Increment ID and Prefix in Magento](http://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419592/how-to-change-order-starting-number-in-magento

Comment: I need to change an invoice already created and shipped